# How to force the update of an Access combobox?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is there a technique I'm overlooking when coding my form?

I have a pair of cascading combos.

1. ComboSource filters the options available for choice in ComboInformation
2. ComboInformation sets the contents of a mandatory field in a table

The rowsource for ComboSource is:

```
SELECT tblSource.SourceID, tblSource.Source
FROM tblSource
ORDER BY tblSource.Source;
```

The rowsource for ComboInformation is:

```
SELECT tblInformation.InformationID, tblInformation.SourceID, tblInformation.InformationSelector
FROM tblInformation
WHERE (((tblInformation.SourceID)=[ComboSource])) OR ((([ComboSource]) Is Null))
ORDER BY tblInformation.InformationSelector;
```

It is valid to select a value in ComboSource which results in the .Listcount for ComboInformation being zero. The user can choose to type a new value in ComboInformation and be prompted to create the relevant item in the Information table linked to the ComboSource entry in the Source table, or they can choose to navigate back to ComboSource to select a different Source.

The problem arises when a user edits an existing record and changes ComboSource to a value for which there is no associated Information records. In the After_Update event for ComboSource I have the following code, intended to update ComboInformation to reflect the new source and force the user to select a new value for ComboInformation (otherwise they could save the record with the old value of Information without realising it).

```
Me.ComboInformation.Requery 'Reflect the current source

'Set a default value for ComboInformation
If Me.ComboInformation.ListCount > 0 Then
     Me.ComboInformation.DefaultValue = Me.InformationTitle.ItemData(0)
Else
     On Error Resume Next 'Ignore inevitable error
     Me.ComboInformation.DefaultValue = Null
     On Error GoTo PROC_ERR 'restore normal error handling
End If

'Force the user to update Information by setting content to "" -- if this isn't done, the
'record can be saved with the 'previous value of Information and the user may not realise 
'they haven't made any change

ComboInformation.SetFocus

If Not Me.NewRecord Then
     If Me.ComboInformation.ListCount = 0 Then
          'Clear info to force it to be updated
          On Error Resume Next 'Ignore inevitable error
          ComboInformation.Text = "" 'Set it to an invalid value
          ComboInformation= Null
          On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
      Else
          ComboInformation= ComboInformation.DefaultValue 'set it to a valid value
          End If
      End If
End If
```

If the user selects a source for which there are no valid information choices, and then chooses to create a new value for Information, no problem. But if they decide to navigate back to ComboSource instead, they get an error message insisting they complete ComboInformation, which they can't do. They can undo the change they made to get back to the previous state, but that isn't an intuitive response to an error message telling them to complete ComboInformation.

Is there either a way to allow them to navigate back to ComboSource when ComboInformation is invalid or another way to force them to update ComboInformation after updating ComboSource before saving the record that doesn't have this issue?

Update about the error message:  I can trap it in Form_Error although the error message isn't generated there -- no other procedures in the stack. The error message is the message associated with the Information field in the Information table (Validation rule: Is Not Null; Validation text; Every piece of evidence must derive from a piece of information)

Further update: I could handle the error (3316) in the Form_OnError but there will be occasions when isn't a 'valid error' that I don't want to ignore...

Other things tried so far:

Refreshing the page doesn't help.

### Demonstration database

There's a database to demo the problem at https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/genquiry/test.accdb

Open the only form in the database, set the Source to S3 and attempt to navigate back to Source to select a different value.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page?  That's my first thought; what happens when you do that?  I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: When you go into Debug mode on the error (holding the "Ctrl" button and pressing the "Pause/Break" button), which line is highlighted?

Comment: Any time the code stops, even if it's a messagebox, Ctrl-Pause-Break should work.  Alternatively, you can add a break point to the VBA code and then step through it until you get the error.

Comment: What about teaching the users to press Escape once (field level) or twice (record level) ? Or Couldn't you use Me.Undo ? Or (not nice, I know) SendKeys Escape(s)

Comment: So the error is happening when you set ComboInformation = Null?  Have you tried setting it to an empty string instead?  Or commenting out that piece and see what happens?  Sorry if any of these suggestions sound stupid or juvenile, but sometimes I overlook the obvious myself and I've been doing it for 20 years.  :o)

Comment: @Johnny There is an error (ignored as per the code I posted) when I set ComboInformation to Null, and ComboInformation.Text to "". The error is trapped/reported when the user does anything that navigates away form from ComboInformation or attempts to save the record. If I comment out that piece, the underlying value of ComboInformation isn't changed but the text displayed is empty (because there's no valid rows for the combo). When the user saves the record or navigates away from it, the unchanged value is saved without the user realising.

Comment: @iDevlop There will be (hopefully) a large number of users who only have documentation and help files to go on -- I can document this as a known restriction but have little faith in most users reading the documentation!

Comment: When you load the main form, have a messagebox pop up that says, "RTFM!"  :o)  This is a strange one.  I'll have to build the form in a test DB and see if I can offer more assistance, I'm a little swamped today at work so I can't do it now.  If I figure anything out, I'll let you know.

Comment: @HansUp error 3316 is (I believe) violation of a validation rule on a data table. If I remove 'On Error Resume Next' then the following line triggers error 2115 (as expected, as "" isn't a valid value for the combo).

Comment: @HansUp, Thanks for the suggestions. Trouble with an unbound combobox is that this is one of 20-odd data entry forms in the app (albeit the only one with cascading combos). I'd like to keep the interface consistent throughout and everywhere else navigating away from the form saves the record. I'll give it a while to see what else comes up -- the app is quite complex with a lot of third party controls so I'll need to do some hacking to upload a usable version that demonstrates the problem with out a lot of clutter. Probably easier to generate a new db to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility:

If I set ComboInformation and ComboInformation.DefaultValue to -1 rather than Null when ComboInformation.Listcount = 0, this avoids triggering the table validation rule (Is Not Null) when the user navigates back to ComboSource. However, it is still an invalid value (as it breaks data integrity between tables) and the user is prevented from exiting the form or saving the record until a valid value is entered (by choosing a different value for Source or creating a value in the Information list).

It works, but it isn't an elegant solution and depends on -1 always being an invalid value for the Automatically-generated InformationID field in the linked Information table, which I don't believe is a safe assumption...

However, if I modify the method slightly to find the lowest existing InformationID field (call this LOWID) and then use LOWID-1 to set ComboInformation, that also works,  and always produces an invalid value for the period it is in use.

Answer (score 0):

I think my last message kind of hit it.  Instead of having the Information combo be bound, set it's Control Source dynamically in the AfterUpdate event of the Source field.  You're trying to forcefully fill a bound field with a NULL when there's a "Is Not Null" validation set up in the table design.  If you unbind it, you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: Take a look at this, particularly the Letting Users Choose Any Item From The Second Combo Box section: http://www.datawright.com.au/access_resources/access_combo_boxes.htm.  I think you want to set the Row Source and not the Record Source, which will make the 2nd combo unbound.

Comment: I think that's similar to the way I set the Row Source already: 

`SELECT qryInformation.InformationID, qryInformation.SourceID, qryInformation.InformationSelector
FROM qryInformation
WHERE (((qryInformation.SourceID)=[Source])) OR ((([Source]) Is Null))
ORDER BY qryInformation.InformationSelector;`

However, Source is never Null in my app because the list of unfiltered Information values would be hopelessly long for a user to choose from.

Comment: My bad, that's what I meant.  :o)  ControlSource will bind the combo to the field, RowSource should not.  Because you want to let them add a new value if necessary, you'll have to put some code in the AfterUpdate event of the 2nd combo to see if the data exists, and if not then add it to the table.  This is where you'll control whether or not you're attempting to save a NULL value.

Comment: The code to see if an item exists and create it if necessary is already in the Not In List event for the combo (which I stripped out of the example db because it's part of a set of Class Modules that add complexity unneeded to demo the problem). But that doesn't help with the use case in which the user selects the wrong source, doesn't want to create a new piece of information but wants to navigate back to source to select a different one. In that case, the after_update event for the 2nd combo is never triggered.

Comment: The thing is, if it's not bound, how can it complain?  That's why it absolutely has to be that the 2nd combo needs to be unbound.  Then if you go back and change the first combo, it will just refresh the available items in the 2nd combo box.  It doesn't try to write to a table, the items in the combo are completely separate.  Right now, it's trying to go back and add a new value to the table as soon as the 2nd combo loses the focus, because it's bound to that Information field.

Comment: Still trying to think my way through this -- I suspect I'm missing the blindingly obvious but...If I unbound this second combo, would I use a hidden bound textbox to ensure the underlying Information data was updated? And code in the form's close event to update that hidden textbox or prevent the closure if Information hadn't been set validly?

Comment: I would use VBA code to open the table, add/edit the record with what's in the combo, and then update the table.  No bound boxes or combos at all, that's the only way to ensure you're not trying to write a NULL to the field that won't accept NULL as an answer.

Comment: I've had record locking problems with that approach before, so I'm wary of it. In the full app, there are a lot of other fields in the bound record that need updating as well.

Comment: That's a different story...  The only other thought I have, then, is to change the value in the AfterUpdate event to something you would never use.  Test the value for NULL, and if it's NULL then change it to "XXXXX" or "99999" or something.  And then in your RowSource query, exclude that value in your WHERE clause.  The end user would never see it, and your table wouldn't balk because you're not trying to write a NULL value.  The only issue I see is that you may end up with duplicate records if your users bounce back and forth between combos a lot.

Comment: Sigh. Using a hidden field doesn't work because updating an unbound combobox doesn't trigger the form's BeforeUpdate event (and I need to trap both saving the record and closing the form).

Comment: Using XXXX or 9999 isn't possible -- the valid values for that field are defined by the user and there's nothing that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to clear the second combo box on the after update?  I wrote a quick test one and it seems to clear it automatically.

I do not think that the issues is whether or not the combo box is bound, but that you are setting focus to the combobox before you might have items in it or knowing if the user wants to add items to it which could be done before they enter.

```
Private Sub cboSource.AfterUpdate()
    cboInformation.Requery

    ' if the combobox doesn't refresh to be empty or have a default after the 
    ' requery check the row source for information. 
    ' This way you don't have to focus the second combo box and run into problems
    ' when you leave it
    Dim db as DAO.database
    Dim rs as DAO.recordset

    Set db = CurrentDB()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblInformation.InformationID, 
                     tblInformation.SourceID, tblInformation.InformationSelector
                     FROM tblInformation
                     WHERE (((tblInformation.SourceID)= " & ComboSource.value & "))  
                     OR (((" & ComboSource.value & " ) Is Null))
                     ORDER BY tblInformation.InformationSelector")

    If rs.recordcount <> 0 then
        cboInformation.SetFocus
    Else
        ' Set and empty value for the combobox so they can't accidentally save the
        ' record with an old value.
        ' Prompt them to either select a new value that has records or create a 
        ' new one here
    End If

    rs.close
    db.close
    Set rs = nothing
    Set db = nothing
end Sub
```

Comment: This approach is a possibility (prompting for confirmation before navigating to an empty combo). I'd probably just test .Listcount to test if the combo is empty though.