# SQL statement for combobox row source

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to define a SQL statement to use as the Row Source for a ComboBox on an MSAccess form. The SQL should select records from a table tblI where a particular table field matches a variant parameter varS set by the user; however, if varS is Null or not present in another table tblS, the SQl should select all records in tblI.

I can code the first parts of this (varS matches or is null):

```
SELECT tblI.ID, tblI.S FROM tblI WHERE ((tblI.S = varS) OR (varS Is Null)) ORDER BY tblI.ID;
```

Where I'm struggling is incorporating the final element (varS not present in tblS). I can code a test for the absence of varS in tblS:

```
Is Null(DLookup("[tbls.ID]","tblS","[tblS.ID]= " & varS))
```

but I can't work out how to incorporate this in the SQL statement. Should this work?

```
SELECT tblI.ID, tblI.S FROM tblI WHERE tblI.S = varS OR varS Is Null OR DLookup("[tbls.ID]","tblS","[tblS.ID]= " & varS) Is Null ORDER BY tblI.ID;
```

When run as a query it returns every record in tblS no matter the value of varS.

Table structure:

tblI contains 2 fields, Autonumber ID and Long S

tblS contains 1 field, Autonumber ID

Comment: *"... a variant parameter varS set by the user"*  What method do you use for the user to supply a value for `varS`?

Comment: @HansUp It's derived from the value selected in a ComboBox; if no value is selected, it's set to a value that doesn't exist in tblS (similar what's described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18407742/1943174)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own approach to this problem would be something like this:

```vb
Private Sub SetComboSource(vID as Variant)
    Dim sSQL as String
    sSQL = "SELECT tblI.ID, tblI.S " & _
        "FROM tblI "
    If IsNull(vID) = False Then
        If IsNumeric(vID) = True Then
            If DCount("ID", "tblS", "ID = " Clng(vID)) > 0 Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE tblI.S = " & CLng(vID)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    sSQL = sSQL & " ORDER BY tblI.ID"
    Me.cboComboBox.RowSource = sSQL
End Sub
```

BTW, I recommend you give your tables and fields more descriptive names and then use aliasing in your SQL, especially for table names. I also think it's best to avoid using Variant variables. I usually use Longs for something like this and I take a value less than 1 to mean that the user didn't select anything, or selected ALL, or whatever meaning you want to derive from it. In other words, my ID's are always a number greater than zero and an ID of less than 1 in a variable means that the ID is empty. Which I use as a signal to create a new record, or to return all records, or whatever meaning you want to derive from it in the given context.

Comment: How do you ensure that IDs are always greater than zero if they're automatically generated? (In the real code, I == Information, and S == Source.)

Comment: Autonumber always assigns numbers greater than zero unless you are using Access replication or SharePoint linked tables. SQL Server, if you're using it, allows you to control the "seed" for your Identity field.

Comment: Ah-ha! Using -1 would be a lot easier all round!

Comment: Or you can use zero. Or you can use zero for one meaning and -1 for a different one. In this case you don't appear to need two different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work;

```
SELECT tblI.ID, tblI.S 
FROM tblI
WHERE tbl.ID=varS
OR varS NOT IN(SELECT ID from tblS)
```